# Unity to Visual Studio : Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported

Tags: c#, dataset, unity-game-engine, webservice-client, hololens

I am designing an application to run on the Microsoft HoloLens using Unity for the user interaction.
The application connects to an asmx webservice to retrieve data.

I have a C# test program to test the connection and data retrieval from the webservice.

I then followed this tutorial to generate a dll based on the webservice wsdl (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AifcMzEbKnA)

If use the following script to generate the dll:

```
@echo off
if exist "Service.xml" (
del MyOwnWS.wsdl
echo Rename
rename Service.xml MyOwnWS.wsdl
echo.
)
echo WSDL
call wsdl MyOwnWS.wsdl -o:MyOwnWS.cs
echo.
echo DMCS
call dmcs /target:library MyOwnWS.cs -r:System.Web.Services,System.Data
echo.
echo Done
```

I added system.Data because my webservice returns DataSet data from a Database.

I dropped that dll in the Assets folder of the Unity project.
I also had to drop System.Data.dll, System.dll, and System.Web.Services.dll in it (took them from C:\Program Files\Unity Hololens 5.4.0b16-HTP\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity folder)

When I use the Unity editor, my application connects to the webservice and retrieve the data without problems.

Next step, I followed this tutorial to make a HoloLens application from Unity (http://hololenshelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/1006/HoloLens-Hello-World)

While it work for their own Hello World, when I tried to build my own project from unity I receive the following error:

> error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported:
>   'C:\Users\UserA\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.dll'
>   and 'J:\Work\MyTestUnity\Assets\System.dll'. Remove one of the
>   duplicate references.Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.3.1.60616

So I added a ProjectFileHook.cs file under Editor with the following content:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge;
using UnityEngine;

// http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/missing-c-references-to-system-data.11361/
// https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d26236e-4a64-4d64-8486-7df95156aba9

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class ProjectFileHook
{
    // necessary for XLinq to save the xml project file in utf8
    class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }

    static void ProcessNodesWithIncludeAttribute(XDocument document, string localName, string includeValue, Action<XElement> action)
    {
        var nodes = document
            .Descendants()
            .Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == localName);

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            var xa = node.Attribute("Include");
            if (xa != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xa.Value) && string.Equals(xa.Value, includeValue))
            {
                action(node);
            }
        }        
    }

    // Remove System.Data from project (not from file system so Unity can compile properly)
    static void RemoveFileFromProject(XDocument document, string fileName)
    {
        ProcessNodesWithIncludeAttribute(document, "None", fileName, element => element.Remove());        
    }

    // Adjust references, by using the default framework assembly instead of local file (remove the HintPath)
    static void RemoveHintPathFromReference(XDocument document, string assemblyName)
    {
        ProcessNodesWithIncludeAttribute(document, "Reference", assemblyName, element => element.Nodes().Remove());        
    }

    static ProjectFileHook()
    {
        ProjectFilesGenerator.ProjectFileGeneration += (string name, string content) =>
        {
            var document = XDocument.Parse(content);

            RemoveFileFromProject(document, @"Assets\System.Data.dll");
            RemoveHintPathFromReference(document, "System.Data");

            RemoveFileFromProject(document, @"Assets\System.Web.Services.dll");
            RemoveHintPathFromReference(document, "System.Web.Services");

            RemoveFileFromProject(document, @"Assets\System.dll");
            RemoveHintPathFromReference(document, "System");

            var str = new Utf8StringWriter();
            document.Save(str);

            return str.ToString();
        };
    }
}
```

But it looks like this does nothing.

I am at a lost about how to fix this at the moment, and I really need experts help to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...
It looks like we cannot use WSDL webservice like that anymore.
Microsoft dropped the support for it in an update no so long ago.
I saw multiple articles about it, but I forgot to keep a bookmark.
So if you want look it up, you will have to go through the WUP documentation.

Instead we ended up using UnityWebRequest and Coroutines to handle the webservice communication.

We also had to update the webservice to enable Get/post calls.